# Generating Satellite assemblies without Resgen

Tags: c#, resx, resgen

We have a process where we generate satellite assemblies with resx files in them. The process relies on Resgen to be present on the system. Is there another way of doing it? This way it is working, but doesn't look elegant because of this dependency.

Reason we want to make it look elegant and less dependent is that we want to run this process on server.

Comment: There is a lot not elegant about it, but if you don't explain why you think you need to do this then it is hard to get good help.  Resgen.exe is a pure managed program and not that big, a good decompiler can provide you with high-quality source code to reverse-engineer.

Comment: `resgen` is a rather thin wrapper around various helper classes, most of them located in [`System.Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.resources). Specifically, take a look at `ResourceWriter`, `ResXResourceReader` and [`StronglyTypedResourceBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.resources.tools.stronglytypedresourcebuilder).

Answer (score 1):

Despite the lack of clarity over exactly what the problem is, I'm going to take a long shot, based on these phrases in the question: "less dependent" and "we want to run this process on server".

I'm guessing that the server being mentioned is the build server and I'm guessing that the concern about dependency relates to Visual Studio, and not wanting to have to install it on the build server due to licensing issues.

You can avoid the dependency on Visual Studio because ResGen is part of the Windows SDK, which can be installed separately, and run from the command line. [More details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(v=vs.100).aspx)

If I'm not right, maybe the OP can clarify the question...